# How does one define locality in a discrete system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, many-body, locality

Consider a discrete system, such as a spin chain or spin net. Generally I think we can define such as system as a (undirected) graph, with various quantum operators (such as spin operators) "living" on the vertices. The Hilbert space is then spanned by the eigenvectors of the operators at all the vertices. How then do we explicitly define what we mean by local. The graph gives a natural notion of distance (in terms of how many edges must be traversed to get from one vertex to another), so does local mean "less than some distance $R$", or simply "containing a finite number of vertices"? What if an operator is formed by two operators which are separated by two edges? Is it still local? Certainly a three-body operator such as $S^z_i S^z_{i+1} S^z_{i+2}$ I would think of as a local operator, but what about $S^z_i S^z_{i+2}$? Or is this simply a matter of defining perhaps a second type of edge which connects next-nearest-neighbors? Clearly an operator such as $h \sum_{i} S^z_i$ where the sum is over all sites is non-local.